# interface method (definition) dependent on another method (definition) defined in same interface

Tags: c#, methods, interface, strategy-pattern

```
public interface ICar
{
    bool IsSpeeds200KMPH(CarData carData);
    bool IsABSEnabled(CarData carData);
    int doors {get;set;}
    int wheels {get;set;}
    bool IsABSAdvanced();
    bool IsSpeedReaches225();
    void drive(CarType car);
}

public class BMW : ICar
{
}

public class Honda : ICar
{
}

// factory class to create car object dynamically
public class CarFactory
{
    public ICar CreateCar(CarType car)
    {
        if(car == TypesOfCars.Honda)
            return new Honda;
        else if(car == TypesOfCars.BMW)
            return new BMW;
        //....
    }
}


//main() method snippet
CarFactory factory = new CarFactory();
ICar carType = facory.CreateCar(DynamicallyProvided_CarTypeValue);
carType.IsABSEnabled(DynamicallyProvided_carData);
carType.IsABSAdvanced();
```

In above example I have implemented ***Strategy Pattern***. My problem is, I have different Car classes implementing **ICar** interface. the method **IsABSAdvanced()** can be called only if the method **IsABSEnabled()** returns true, otherwise exclusively it should return false. Thus how I can make one interface method(definition) dependent on another method(definition) defined in the same interface? Is there any way to limit the restriction to interface level, such that anyone who access **IsABSAdvanced()** shoudln't know that it actually checks **IsABSEnabled()** method internally. Is there such feasibility or else how I can achieve it?

Comment: Have you considered adding an abstract class between your interface and concrete class to handle that?

Comment: Might be better asked on Code Review rather than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are abstract classes.

Interfaces only hold informations about the API a class should hold - not the logic that comes with it.

If you want logic ontop of it, you have a few options - one, for example:

```
public interface ICar
{
    bool IsSpeeds200KMPH(CarData carData);
    bool IsABSEnabled(CarData carData);
    int doors {get;set;}
    int wheels {get;set;}
    bool ABSAdvanced{get;};
    bool IsSpeedReaches225();
    void drive(CarType car);
}

public abstract class AbstractCar : ICar {
    public bool ABSAdvanced {
        get {
            if(!isABSEnabled()) {
                return false;
            }
            /* some additional logic based on the interface */
            /* ... */
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and then all cars extends `AbstractCar` - since `AbstractCar` is an abstract class it won't be able to be instantiated into an object.

Also your question probably can be simplified by:

```
public abstract class AbstractCar : ICar {
    public bool ABSAdvanced { get {return isAbsEnabled();} }
}
```

Which then again makes `ABSAdavanced` redundant if `isABSEnabled` is part of the public API depending on the implementation details.